# SQL: How to split a row into multiple calculated rows

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables like this:

```
ProductsTable
---------------------------------------------
ProductID   ProductName    ProductDescription
----------- -------------- ------------------
1           Name1          Description1
2           Name2          Description2

ValuesTable
--------------------------------
ProductID   Period         Value
----------- -------------- -----
1           2014Q1         100
1           2014Q2         110
1           2014Q3         105
2           2014Q1         80
2           2014Q2         85
2           2014Q3         90

MonthsTable
--------------------------------
Month       Period         Weeks
----------- -------------- -----
2014-Jan    2014Q1         4
2014-Feb    2014Q1         4
2014-Mar    2014Q1         5
```

What I want is a query that can provide the following result:

```
ProductID     ProductName    Month      Value
1             Name1          2014-Jan   30.77
1             Name1          2014-Feb   30.77
1             Name1          2014-Mar   38.46
```

The value of the last column will be determined by the following formula:

```
=(PV / SWP * MW)
```

where

- `PV`  : Period Value
- `SWP` : Sum of weeks of the period
- `MW`  : Weeks of the month

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please tag your question with the RDBMS and version that you are using (Oracle 11g, MySQL, SQL Server 2008, etc)

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any splitting here.  simply joining the talbes will result in the first 3 columns.  The 4th becomes a calculated value using formula you've entered.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort. Please update your question with the code you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.productID, p.productName, m.month, (v.value / swp * m.weeks)
FROM productsTable p, monthstable m, valuestable v,
     (SELECT m1.period, sum(m1.weeks) as swp 
      FROM monthsTable m1 
      GROUP BY m1.period) x
WHERE x.period = v.period AND p.productID = v.productID
      --and p.productID = 1 --if you want the results only for product 1
```

Another way would be using `JOIN`s (if I'm not wrong):

```
SELECT p.productID, p.productName, month, (v.value / x.swp * m.weeks)
FROM productsTable p JOIN valuesTable v ON p.productID = v.productID
     JOIN (SELECT m1.period, sum(m1.weeks) as swp 
           FROM monthsTable m1 
           GROUP BY m1.period) x ON x.period = v.period
     JOIN monthsTable m ON x.period = m.period
```

You only must to join all your tables by the correct field and calculate the last column applying directly your formula.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+:

```
;WITH Months AS
(
    SELECT  *, 
            SUM(Weeks) OVER(PARTITION BY Period) QuarterWeeks
    FROM MonthsTable
)
SELECT  V.ProductID,
        P.ProductName,
        V.Value / M.QuarterWeeks * M.Weeks Value
FROM ValuesTable V
INNER JOIN ProductsTable P
    ON V.ProductID = P.ProductID
LEFT JOIN Months M
    ON V.Period = M.Period
```

Comment: well if you're going to do a `SUM() OVER` why bother with the CTE? e.g.  `V.Value / SUM(Weeks) OVER(PARTITION BY p.productID , v.Period)  * M.Weeks Value`

Comment: @ConradFrix Why not?, I find that syntax very clean and makes it clear what it is that I'm trying to do